# Getting a number and a unit from input as a double and a string -- Programming: Principles and Practices Using C++

Tags: c++, string, input, double

I've been going through Bjarne Stroustrup's Programming: Principles and Practices Using C++ for my own benefit. This is not homework and this is not for school.

I'm at my wit's end with this drill from Chapter 4. I'm supposed to take in a number and a unit from input, store the number as a double and the unit as a string in a while loop, and keep track of the largest and smallest numbers seen so far. It works perfectly for units that are one character like "m" or "g", but when I enter a two-character unit such as "cm" or "ft" the loop ends and the program terminates. Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double temp = 0;
    string unit = " ";
    double largest = 0;
    double smallest = 0;

    while (cin >> temp >> unit)
    {
        if (largest == 0 && smallest == 0)
        {
            largest = temp;
            smallest = temp;
            cout << "That's the largest number seen so far.\n";
            cout << "That's the smallest number seen so far.\n";
        }
        else if (temp >= largest)
        {
            largest = temp;
            cout << "That's the largest number seen so far.\n";
        }
        else if (temp <= smallest)
        {
            smallest = temp;
            cout << "That's the smallest number seen so far.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << temp << '\n';
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I really appreciate any help in solving this problem. It's driving me insane.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the program you show us, exactly as you show us? [Because it seems to work fine](http://ideone.com/zKMRsS).

Comment: Looks like your compiler assumed a string was a char without the `string` header...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg If that's the case, then the only problem I can think of would have to be the environment I'm running it in. I'm using Xcode and testing it in Xcode's console simulator.

Comment: @SergeBallesta #include <string> still hasn't solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to `#include <string>` before it would even compile, and I added extra "printf()" stmts for debugging.

But your code should work: one character, or many characters.

Here's my (modified) code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double temp = 0;
    string unit = " ";
    double largest = 0;
    double smallest = 0;

    while (cin >> temp >> unit)
    {
        cout << "NEXT: temp=" << temp << ", unit=" << unit << "\n";
        if (largest == 0 && smallest == 0)
        {
            largest = temp;
            smallest = temp;
            cout << "That's the largest number seen so far.\n";
            cout << "That's the smallest number seen so far.\n";
        }
        else if (temp >= largest)
        {
            largest = temp;
            cout << "That's the largest number seen so far.\n";
        }
        else if (temp <= smallest)
        {
            smallest = temp;
            cout << "That's the smallest number seen so far.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << temp << '\n';
        }

    }
    cout << "DONE: temp=" << temp << ", unit=" << unit << ", smallest=" << smallest << ", largest=" << largest << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

And here's sample output:

```
12 cm
NEXT: temp=12, unit=cm
That's the largest number seen so far.
That's the smallest number seen so far.
6 "
NEXT: temp=6, unit="
That's the smallest number seen so far.
18 feet
NEXT: temp=18, unit=feet
That's the largest number seen so far.
^D
DONE: temp=18, unit=feet, smallest=6, largest=18
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
It still won't work for me. Inputting 12cm gives this result:

DONE: temp=0, unit=m, smallest=7, largest=7

Comment: You need a SPACE between "12" and "cm".  Since you're asking for two variables - you need whitespace (a "delimiter") to separate them.

Comment: @AnthonyRossello that is because cin fails because it tried to read a apparent string "12cm" and not a number like it needed. The rectification is to add a space or a return carriage between 12 and cm, it will then read t "12" as a number into temp and "cm" as a string into unit

Answer (score -1):

Okay, thanks for all your help everyone.

It seems the issue was compiler/system specific. My code was having issues with OSX's default compiler, but running the same code on Windows 10 using MinGW as a compiler worked flawlessly. What a strange bug. If anyone has any tips on how to get this program to work on OSX using its default compiler, it'd be very appreciated.

Comment: It's not a "compiler bug".  See my response below.